# The code reads from a specified offset to the specified number of bytes in a file

Tags: c, linux, unix

The code reads the specified number of bytes from a specified offset in a file, I have handled the partial reads and bytes > buf_size conditions. Could anyone review the code? and say whether the handling strategy is good. The constraint I am  not allowed to use system calls other than open, close, read, write,Thanks a ton.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define buf_size 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int bytes;
    int offset;
    int fd; 
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size];
    int rlen = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if (argc != 4)
        error(1, 0, "Too many or less than the number of arguments");
    file = argv[1];
    offset = atoi(argv[2]);
    bytes = atoi(argv[3]);
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    printf("The values of the file descriptor is : %d\n", fd);
    if (fd == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error while opening the file\n");

    while (1) {
        rlen = read(fd, buf, offset);
        if (rlen == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error in reading the file\n");
        len = len + rlen;
        if(len == offset) {
            len = 0;
            while (1) {
                rlen = read(fd, buf, bytes);
                if (rlen == -1)
                    error(1, errno, "Error in reading the file\n");
                if (rlen == 0)
                    return 0;
                len = len + rlen;
                for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) 
                    putchar(buf[i]);
                if (len == bytes) {
                    printf("\nSuccess\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                bytes = bytes - rlen;
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fails with large `offset, bytes`**

`read(fd, buf, offset);` reads out of `buf[]` bounds when `offset > buf_size`.  Same for `bytes`.  This should be tested.

Unclear why `buf[buf_size]` is so small (5).  How about 4096 or 1 Meg?

**Handle large offset**

I'd expect code to handle offsets far larger than the `sizeof buf`.  Looping on `read(fd, buf, offset);` if needed.

**`int` math**

Files sizes can well exceed `INT_MAX`.  For `offset, bytes`, I'd use `long long`.

**Unneeded loop**

Rather than a `for()` loop `for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) putchar(buf[i]);`, use `write(1, ...)`.

**Missing `close()`**

**Function Limitations**

OP has "not allowed to use system calls other than open, close, read, write".  What about `error()`, `printf()`, `atoi()`, `putchar()` - or are those classified differently?

With such a limit, looks like a lot of `includes`.

**Algorithm flaw?**

The first `while (1)` loop looks wrong.

Either the first iteration will get the expect `offset` number of bytes and proceed to the 2nd `while ()`.

Or

it will read insufficient number of bytes (for reasons other than no -more bytes will ever exist) and loop again, trying to read `offset` bytes again.  I'd expect that `offset` would have been reduced by the previous `rlen`.  Without that reduction, `if(len == offset)` may never be satisfied as reading too many `offset` bytes is then possible.

I'd expect 2 `while` loops that are not nested.  First to read the `offset` bytes, next to read the `bytes`.

Further this could be sub-function calls.  Something like:

```
if (read_bytes(handle, offset, no_echo) == OK) {
  if (read_bytes(handle, bytes, echo_to_stdout) == OK) {
    success();
  }
}
fail();
```